# Find if a ListViewGroup already exists

Tags: c#, winforms, collections

Classic Windows form type of interface, I have two ListViews, one on the left (SongsAvailable) and one on the right (SongsInLibrary).  Select an entry on the list on the left, click a button to add it to the list on the right, but put it in the right group (if it exists.)  I have this code

```
private void AddSelected(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool rc = false;
    foreach (ListViewItem item in SongsAvailable.SelectedItems)
    {
        var s = item.SubItems[0].Text.Substring(0, 1);
        TestGroup = new ListViewGroup(s, s);
        rc = SongsInLibrary.Groups.Contains(TestGroup);
        if (!rc) { // create a new group and add it  }
        SongsInLibrary.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { item.SubItems[0].Text, item.SubItems[1].Text, item.SubItems[2].Text, item.SubItems[3].Text }, ListGroup ));
    }
}
```

The return rc is always false (which doesn't surprise me, a new ListViewGroup can't already exist in the Groups collection) so I always wind up adding new groups.  Documentation on "Contains" is also frustratingly terse.  Short of iterating through all the groups, how do I find if A group already exists?

Comment: If you set `TestGroup` equal to a `new ListViewGroup` instance, how do you expect that it would equal some other instance (which would be required for `Contains` to return `true`)?

Comment: I did mention ithat in my question.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you're discovering the group that you need to search for (what is `s` supposed to represent?), but it appears from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewgroupcollection?view=netcore-3.1) that the `ListViewGroupCollection` class (which is the type for `SongsInLibrary.Groups`) implements `IList`, so you should be able to iterate over the items to find the one you want using a normal loop. Have you tried that?

Comment: For example I have a song that starts with the letter "A".  I want to put it in the "A" group.  So yes, I could do something like (pseudocode) foreach group in lvm.groups, if group.name.equals("A"), add item using that group.  If I've gone through all the groups and not found "A", then add a new group and add the item using that (end pseudocode).  But that seems horribly inefficient and definitely inelegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about these `ListViewGroup` and `ListViewItem` classes, but since no one else has answered, here's at least one way to do it:

1. Use the `Cast` method (from `System.Linq`) to cast the `ListViewGroupCollection` to an `IEnumerable<ListViewGroup>`
2. Get the `FirstOrDefault` group that has the header we're looking for
3. If the group doesn't exist, create a new one and add it to `SongsInLibrary.Groups`
4. Remove the item from `SongsAvailable` (which appears to be required in order to add it to a new group)
5. Set the item's `Group` to the group we want it in
6. Add the item to our `SongsInLibrary` collection

Doing it this way avoids the problem with calling `Contains` with a `new Group` (that will never exist)

For example:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in SongsAvailable.SelectedItems)
{
    // Determine the group we want to add this to (the first letter of the item)
    var groupHeader = item.Text.Substring(0, 1);

    // Get the first group that matches, or null if it's not there
    var group = SongsInLibrary.Groups.Cast<ListViewGroup>()
        .FirstOrDefault(g => g.Header == groupHeader);

    // If it's not there, create it and add it
    if (group == null)
    {
        group = new ListViewGroup(groupHeader);
        SongsInLibrary.Groups.Add(group);
    }

    // Move the song to the goup and add the song to the library
    SongsAvailable.Items.Remove(item);
    item.Group = group;
    SongsInLibrary.Items.Add(item);
}
```

There may be a better way, but from the quick glance at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.groups?view=netcore-3.1) for `ListView.Groups`, they don't seem overly simple to work with.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  And as an added bonus, I rethought about adding the song to the list.  I was creating a new object (so it would be in both, which meant I had to check to see if it's already there first.)  I'll have to rework a couple things when populating the original lists and when moving back from the right to the left, but that shouldn't be anything major.